# MySQL Insert with PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Hi everyone im stuck with this code im practically new to php...
what im trying to do is,im trying to insert into the database one field called Id_Obj and its a VarChar but when im trying to send it it tells me "Unknown Column 'Id_Obj4' in 'field List'
i really got no idea what to do  the insert looks like this
i forgot it was different when passing a variable and just the string so it really look like this i was lazy the first time sorry :S

```
while($info=mysql_fetch_Array($data))
{
print "name :".$info['Id']." ";
$count=$info['Id'];
}
    $t="INSERT INTO Table_Faces(Id_Obj,Num_Sides)VALUES(";
    $t = $t."IdObj$count".",".$_GET["ns"];
    $t = $t.")";
    mysql_query($t);
```

the fields in the database are Id,Id_Obj,Num_Sides

help me please

Comment: What are you trying to do with the string `"IdObj$count"`?  It might be useful to `echo $t;` and take a look at your query -- you're probably not building it how you think you are.

Comment: you can find out what the insert looks like by doing `print $t;` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around your insert values

```
while($info=mysql_fetch_Array($data))
{
    print "name :".$info['Id']." ";
    $count=$info['Id'];
}

$t="INSERT INTO Table_Faces(Id_Obj,Num_Sides)VALUES(";
$t = $t."'IdObj$count'".",'".$_GET["ns"]."'";
$t = $t.")";
mysql_query($t);
```

ie  `INSERT INTO Table_Faces (Id_Obj, Num_Sides) VALUES('asdf','foo')`

I also recommend you use mysql_real_escape_string on all of the variables you are inserting in a table to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Note that `mysql_real_escape_string` does not eliminate all SQL injection vulnerabilities under certain circumstances.  You'd be better of using proper parametrized queries instead.

Comment: I didn't know that, that's good to know.  I usually use parameterized queries and mysqli.

Comment: @cdhowie, Which circumstances? Or should I ask that as a separate question?

Comment: DAMN!!! U ROCK DUDE THIS ANSWER WORKED que te lluevan culitos.. thank you very much

Comment: @TRiG: IIRC, it has to do with the connection's collation, but I forget the specifics.

Comment: @cdhowie: Sorry my mistake, I haven't had my coffee yet, I fixed my answer to SQL-injection ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the values in your query should be quoted. Try this:

```
$t='INSERT INTO Table_Faces(Id_Obj,Num_Sides)VALUES(';
$t .= '"IdObj' . $count . '", "' . $_GET["ns"] . '")';
mysql_query($t);
```

Note that you are explicitly pasting an $_GET[] variable into your query, which is a direct security issue, everybody who has the URL can use SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a new field called `Id_Obj4` in the table `Table_Faces` or are you trying to add a value of `Id_Obj4` into the field `Id_Obj`?

Try

```
$t  = 'INSERT INTO Table_Faces (Id_Obj, Num_Sides) VALUES ';
$t .= '("IdObj' . $count . '", "' . $_GET['ns'] . '")';
```

Note that there's a massive potential for Bobby Tables errors right there.